# The meaning of * in the code

Tags: c++

I have faced with a code like below

```
bool* keyStates = new bool[256];
void keyPressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    keyStates[key] = true; // Set the state of the current key to pressed  
}
```

and there is a question in it for me.
 as you can see `key` is a `char`, so its value is something like `'a'`.
and `keyStates` is a set of pointers to bool variable.

Therefore, i cannot understand why something like `keyStates['a']` should be true?

It seems to me it works like an associative array. Right?

Comment: Caveat, should you ever write code like this yourself: There is a reason for the "unsigned" part of the parameter type. If you do not specify the signedness of char, it might be signed, accessing memory outside of the array for non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each character is represented by a unique number, depending on the representation<sup>1</sup>. This unique number representation is used as an index in the dynamically allocated `bool` array `keyStates[]`, in your case:

```
char key = 'a';
keyStates[key] = true;
```

would mean set the element with index `97` to `true`. Practically all characters are unique keys/indexes to the elements of the array.

Now, to answer you question:

> Therefore, I cannot understand why something like keyStates['a'] should be true?

In the definition of `char`, one reads:

> `char`: Smallest addressable unit of the machine that can contain basic character set. It is an **integer type**. Actual type can be either signed or unsigned depending on the implementation.

Therefore, a `char` is a small integer and it is a subject to the same integer (or pointer) arithmetic similar to integers.

### Note:

The argument of the function is `unsigned char`, as this type of variables have values between `0` and `255`, while signed chars (i.e. `char`) have values between `-128` and `127`, not covering all the indexes of the array and possibly accessing memory outside of it.

---

<sup>1. [ASCII (extended ASCII)](http://www.asciitable.com/) is one example where all characters are represented with values from `0` to `255`.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

> and `keyStates` is a set of pointers to bool variable.

No. `keyStates` is a pointer to first element of dynamically allocated array. You should know that `char` can be used as array indices. Therefore, `keyStates['a']` is of `bool` type. It is equivalent to `*(keyStates + 'a') = *(keyStates + 97) = keyStates[97]`. (ASCII value of `'a'` is `97`).

Comment: A comment would be appreciated if something is wrong with this answer.

Comment: The answer could have stated more explicitely that char is an integral type and can therefore be used for array indexing. This was obviously what the OP did not recognize when he speculated about keystates being an associative array.